# Access UINavigationViewController from UIImageView class

Tags: ios

I have a UIImageView with a custom class. When the image is pressed the class should push a new view controller, however I don't seem to be able to get a reference to the current UINavigationController. I would usually do self.navigationController, but here I can't.
I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
[self.window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:browser animated:YES];
```

Comment: `self.window.rootViewController.navigationController` is always nil. Because the rootViewController has no parent. (it would'nt be the ROOT-view controller if it had a parent.)

Comment: What is the app hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your Custom Image View a delegate:

```
@protocol CustomImageViewDelegate;
@interface CustomImageView : UIImageView
    @property (weak, nonatomic) id<CustomImageViewDelegate> delegate;
@end
@protocol CustomImageViewDelegate
    - (void)imageViewPressed:(CustomImageView *)imageView
@end
```

Make you view controller the delegate. When the image is pressed, you do `[self.delegate imageViewPressed:self`.

Your view controller will have the implementation:

```
- (void)imageViewPressed:(CustomImageView *)imageView
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:browser animated:YES];
}
```

---

Or give your view a Navigation Controller property:

```
@interface CustomImageView : UIImageView
    @property (weak, nonatomic) UINavigationController navigationController;
@end
```

Then you can use `[self.navigationController pushViewController:browser animated:YES]` directly on your Custom Image View.

You'll have to set the `navigationController` property, iOS won't do it for you.

On your controller add the line

```
self.yourCustomImageViewProperty.navigationController = self.navigationController;
```

---

This is a very basic response, but I hope it steers you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

1. First make `UIImageView to UserInteractionEnabled = YES`.
2. Check that `self.window.rootViewController.navigationController` is
   nil or not .

Answer (score 0):

If the root view controller is already a navigation controller, then you could do this:

```
UINavigationController *nav = self.window.rootViewController;
[nav pushViewController:browser animated:YES];
```

Comment: this code gives an incompatible hello sign (incompatible pointer types initialising UINavigationController with an expression of type UIViewController)

Comment: Then according to @Michael's comment this cannot be right

Comment: Just add `(UINavigationController *)` directly before `self.window.rootViewController;` to resolve that. So it looks like `UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;`

Comment: Yes, or simply UINavigationController *nav = (id) self.window.rootViewController;